# How to SpeedUp? Small Wordpress page, 447kb, load time ~3sec

Tags: wordpress, cdn, page-speed, google-pagespeed

**Testing:**

Under NameCheap shared hosting my 5 page Wordpress site first page is 447kb HTTPS and 23 requests **but takes 3 seconds to load** (**pingdom**).  That is rather poor right?  Tried a second time increased to 3.19 seconds.

Following the advice from  [Pingdom repots slow site][1] I checked with **[uptrends tools](https://www.uptrends.com/tools/)**.  They report 0.9 second for San Diego to load the site but **4.9 seconds for New York**.

My Theme flat.min.css?ver=1.7.4 is the single largest file at 159kb.

I have cloud flare setup but caching disabled since with HTTPS does not work without paying for a more expensive cloud flare plan.  Only three plugs are used: Custom CSS Manager, Wordfence Security, WordPress HTTPS.

Google PageSpeed Insights report:

> 57 / 100 Speed RED
>
> Should Fix:
>   Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript, and CSS in above-the-fold content,
>   Enable compression
>
> Consider Fixing:
>   Reduce server response time, Leverage browser caching, Minify HTML, Minify CSS

**Attempted Remediation:**

Using recommendations to aim for a 1 second page load time and suggestions, [WordPress speed – How to reduce your load time to under 1 second](http://wpcurve.com/wordpress-speed/)

Enabled compression (cPanel Optimize Website) on everything and that raised Google PageSpeed score to 72/100 Yellow.  GTmetrix reports compression is missing a font that offers 20% 16kb space savings.  How? Google PageSpeed reports service response time is a slow 0.56 seconds.  ow using Wordfense Falcon Caching.

**How can I minimize my Theme's CSS & Javascript or run the theme javascript async.  I think my biggest issues are Remove Render-Blocking JavaScript, Minimize CSS/JS, and get CDN.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it from my location (east Canada) and it took about 5 seconds for the page to load.

The first thing that stands out to me is that you have almost nothing cached. That's what google means when they tell you to "Leverage browser caching".

In your webpagetest.org test, look at the caching section for all lines beginning with "(No max-age or expires)". You need to configure your server to cache static files such as your icon and image files.

Assuming you use apache, you can add the following to your .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
ExpiresActive On
<filesMatch ".(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|ico|pdf|js|htm|html)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</filesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

What it does is makes files ending in gif, png, jpg, jpeg, ico, pdf, js, htm and html have a cache lifetime of 2592000 seconds (which is a long time) when its served to a client from the server. This alone will give you a better score in the caching department.

If you can, try to eliminate external files that you believe are required for your page. See if you can pick the most basic theme in wordpress then create your site off that with no fancy effects.

The more external files a page needs to load, the slower the server will be overall for everyone.

Comment: thanks, it looks like that helped some.  Google PageSpeed Insights upto yellow 72/100.  Reduce server response time and Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content are its two primary suggestions.

Comment: render blocking CSS is when your site requires external CSS styles. Using in-line stylesheets solves that issue. For render blocking javascript, move the javascript towards the end of the HTML (before the `</body>` tag) or make the javascript load asynchronously.